# seek bar design with following design using android xml

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV8ri.png)

Need UI design for above image in android xml

I am not able to create design same like above Image, I was stuck with height, width and background in alert dialog

I was using DialogFragment().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.